# django-auth-ldap with Active Directory not pulling "Domain Users" group

Tags: python, django, django-auth-ldap

I have the following in my `settings.py` which is working fine and authenticating against Active Directory. This config is pulling all groups into the Django Admin app apart from the "Domain Users" group which I need to use in my current project. Does anyone know why this is the only group which is not showing up in the Admin app??

`settings.py`

```
# LDAP Settings

# Baseline configuration
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldaps://DC1@example.com:636"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "user@example.com"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "password"
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("DC=example,DC=com", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(&(objectClass=user)(samAccountName=%(user)s))")
AUTH_LDAP_CONNECTION_OPTIONS = {
    ldap.OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL: 0,
    ldap.OPT_REFERRALS: 0,
}

# Populate Django user from LDAP directory
AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail"
}

# Set up the basic group parameters.
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("dc=example,dc=com",
                                    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(objectClass=group)")

AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = ActiveDirectoryGroupType(name_attr='cn')

# Pull AD groups into Django
AUTH_LDAP_MIRROR_GROUPS = True

# This is the default, but I like to be explicit.
AUTH_LDAP_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER = True

# Configure both backend systems
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = {
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out with this?

Answer (score 0):

"Domain Users" group is located inside the User container

"cn=Users,dc=example,dc=com"

See this link with the solution.

https://github.com/ednaldodias/django-adldap-sync-primarygroup